# Truncate Datetime to Second (Remove Milliseconds) in Sybase

Tags: sql, perl, sybase

When executing below query from Perl script, the datetime output is displayed as

```
mon dd yyyy hh:mm:ss:nnn
```

I need to truncate milliseconds from datetime:

```
mmm  dd yyyy 12:00:00:000AM
```

The filed is displaying correctly in database, only when run from script and result redirected to a text file, I am facing this problem. 
how can I make the script to not display milliseconds? I need to retain AM/PM

Can someone help with this problem?

Query:

```
select fieldA, fieldB, fieldC, xyzDate from tableT where xyzDate = '@abcDate'
```

Output:

```
|||47.1000000000|Nov  4 2014 12:00:00**:000**AM|USD|US|CPS EOD
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: ysth, yes it is a colon and not a period. perl script is not reflecting the datetime formatting.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the Perl code that executes the query and prints the result. Please also include the exact output you're getting from your Perl script.

Comment: Also be aware that since you've already accepted an answer, people are likely to think that your problem has been solved and it may not get a lot of attention.

Comment: @ ThisSuitIsBlackNot Edited per suggestion.

Comment: Just showing the query isn't enough...we also need to see the Perl code that *executes* the query and prints the result. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to see the type of information we need in order to help you.

Comment: Although it seems like you are not actually using the query that [Rahul suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26849352)...I don't see `dateadd` anywhere in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note sure about retaining the `AM/PM` part and neither have any way to test it but try this once using `DATETIME` functions

```
declare @dt datetime;
set @dt = 'mmm dd yyyy 12:00:00:123AM';

select dateadd(millisecond, -datepart(millisecond, @dt), @dt);
```

Comment: Thanks Rahul. Query is working as expected. 
But when executing the same from Perl script, the datetime output is still displayed as mon dd yyyy hh:mm:ss:nnn

Comment: @RamyaSR, Not sure about that. Answered solely cause it was related to SQL. You may want to post that as separate question with `Perl` tag to get specific answer. May be the problem is with `Perl` DBD/DBI module but can't say for sure though. Do accept the answer if it's helpful.

Comment: If you read the question, the OP says that *“The [field] is displaying correctly in database, only when run from script and result redirected to a text file, I am facing this problem”*. The OP's comment on your solution shows that your suggestion makes no difference at all.

Comment: the OPs post suggests that this would be a solution if he actually tried it

Comment: @Borodin, before making a comment; go and check the question edit history. Probably then you will fill to remove your above comment.